# Running WEbDriver tests

Tags: selenium, webdriver

So i have been writing Selenium tests for a while now and i have been running the only from the IDE untill now.

i would like to be able to write a script that runs all my tests sequentialy.
I am using the testng framework with eclipse and selenium-2.0b3 jar.

What i'd like is eventually to have a file like "runSeleniumTests.bat" witch just runs them and gives me some sort of report when in finishes.

if anyone has an idea, it will be very greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This has 4 options for how to run testng tests the xml file should include all your tests
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

You could also try to use maven and as long as your tests are annotated correctly and in /src/test/java they will all be run for you with `mvn integration-test` (as long as you have the proper dependencies defined and I believe maven-surefire-plugin). This might be more difficult to setup initially but usually pays off.